# 4.10.1 Python ATNDeserializer broken?

Tags: python, antlr

The Java implementation continues to work fine, but the Python implementation, which has also been working fine before the upgrade to 4.10.1, now throws a TypeError on line 89 in adjust of ATNDeserializer.py

Is this a known bug?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vickery/Projects/dgw_processor/dgw_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ReqBlockLexer import ReqBlockLexer
  File "/Users/vickery/Projects/dgw_processor/ReqBlockLexer.py", line 421, in <module>
    class ReqBlockLexer(Lexer):
  File "/Users/vickery/Projects/dgw_processor/ReqBlockLexer.py", line 423, in ReqBlockLexer
    atn = ATNDeserializer().deserialize(serializedATN())
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 61, in deserialize
    self.reset(data)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 91, in reset
    temp = [ adjust(c) for c in data ]
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 91, in <listcomp>
    temp = [ adjust(c) for c in data ]
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 89, in adjust
    v = ord(c)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Answer (score 1):

I had failed to update antlr4-python3-runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Did you regenerate your lexers and parsers?
I have the same error when I used v4.9.2 to generate my code. But when I updated antlr4-python3-runtime to v4.10, the error was fixed.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was trying to build the lexer and parser with the wrong version of the runtime.